# DAO Layer always required in Hibernate ORM?

Tags: hibernate, database-design, orm, dao

I think I have completely confused myself in implementing Hibernate ORM.

My understanding is that Hibernate lets you eliminate DAO layer. Not that it is mandatory (or even advantageous), but it does let you do so.

But, in my case, I don't see how this can happen.
I will explain my case using two entities of my system - Company and CompanyRegistration.

Company Class -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
public class Company extends LightEntity implements BaseSerializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "ContactNumber1")
    private String contactNumber1;

    @Column(name = "ContactNumber2")
    private String contactNumber2;

    @Column(name = "EMail")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CompanyRegistration> companyRegistrations;

    public Company(String code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // getters and setters follow..
}
```

CompanyRegistration Class -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CompanyRegistration")
public class CompanyRegistration extends LightEntity implements BaseSerializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "RegistrationNumber")
    private String registrationNumber;
    @Column(name = "YearOfRegistration")
    private String yearOfRegistration;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CompanyId", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    public CompanyRegistration(String registrationNumber, String yearOfRegistration, Company company) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
        this.yearOfRegistration = yearOfRegistration;
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }
    public String getYearOfRegistration() {
        return yearOfRegistration;
    }
    public String getCompanyId() {
        return company.Id;
    }
}
```

In the Company class, I have specified `CascadeType.All` so that Hibernate takes care of the cascade operations of save, update, delete, etc., along with persisting them to the database. Thus, any changes in CompanyRegistration collection will be reflected to its database table directly. Thus, Hibernate will cater to my needs of persisting the CompanyRegistration collection.

However, I still will have to use a DAO layer in order to persist the Company object, won't I? I understand that I can use HQL in that layer instead of standard SQL, but that's not my concern. There is still a separate layer.

It is most likely that I have misunderstood the concepts here.

So, my question is Is this how things work? 
Also, what advantages other than caching (a big plus for me here), auto persisting collections (but not the owner object) and HQL (can't comment on this as I haven't used it yet) does Hibernate provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you havent understood the meaning of `DAO layer` aka `Data Access Objects` layer itself. Whatever ORM tool you use, you always require a DAO layer.Every entity has its DAO class in DAO layer. It is this layer each entity class creates session objects and call hibernate api's i.e save(),update(),delete()etc on the **persistent** object. And yes you need to learn about [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) in hibernate. We use it in for certain function of hibernate like createQuery() api. ANd read [this](http://corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/DataAccessObject.htm) about DAO pattern.

Comment: I agree. ORM is not a replacement/overriding pattern of DAO. They should be used together. Right?

Comment: Right buddy,You can always implement design pattern of your choise or requirement,but at the end you have a DAO layer for accessing database with you ORM tool.

Answer (score 1):

Your DAO implementation will be used only to invoke methods from the EntityManager, you don't need to create a SQL or HQL to insert, you can easily do it by invoking the persist method of the EntityManager.

```
public class CompanyDAOImpl{

    public void save(Company company){ 
        entityManager.persist(company) 
    }

}
```

The entityManager can be set by a spring configuration or you can set it to the object... it depends how you create it.

Comment: entityManager.remove(object); entityManager.find(class, id); are also other methods that you can invoke. You can take a look at the javadoc for a better understanding http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Comment: OK. This means that I would have to use HQL only in case of specific data retrieval, which EntityManager might not be able to perform, right?

Comment: Also, isn't Session better than EntityManager for Hibernate session management?

Comment: Yes, but you can also use HQL to insert, delete, etc... which I never needed to use

Comment: Yes. I get that. But I think it is better to take advantage of EntityManager/Session as much as possible.

Comment: I use EntityManager because my of spring configuration, I am not sure about the difference between them

Answer (score 1):

the biggest advantage behind Hibernate is Object Relational Mapping. It automatically do the mapping for you between your relational data and your object. Without Hibernate, you will have to write your own code to manually create domain object, or list of objects from the data set you retrieved each time.

One example, when you retrieve an object using Hibernate,`session.get(objectId)`, it returns a so called managed object. When the transaction is committed, Hibernate will do a dirty check (check for modification) on this object and flush the change to db if necessary. You don't actually need to call update operation.

Other benefits include:

- LazyLoading: relational collection can be loaded later when needed
  rather than everything at once. It improves performance because if
  your collection is large, loading everything when you have needed it
  consume a lot of memory.
- Concurrency Handling: Hibernate provides you    with the features to
  handle concurrency, such as OptimisticLocking.    If you using
  OptimisticLocking, every time a object is saved to    database, it
  will check for a conflict in the version column and    throw
  exception if there is.

Otherwise you would have to implements your own to handle these scenario.

Regarding the difference between EntityManager and Session, they are the two ORM API implementation by Hibernate. EntityManager is the implementation of [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API). There are a few differences between syntax and usages. You can choose to use either of these. And you better stick with one. I have seen program to mixing between these two.

Comment: Btw, what is your concern of adding an extra DAO layer ? There is alternative of putting your Data Access code in the model layer rather than in an separate layer. You can see the implementation of code generated by `Spring Roo`

Comment: I wasn't concerned about adding a DAO layer, but about the Data Access code; whether it exists withing the model or in a separate layer. But, now I understand that ORM is not a replacement of DAO pattern. That was my misconception.